# How to get element by id from the same parent

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `div` in which I have a `button` and a `textarea`. What is the easiest way to get my `hands` on a `child` from a given div by its `id`?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <script src="main.js"></script>
        <p>Welcome to Adrian's script</p>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Panel">
                <button id="panelBtn" class="button" onclick="method(document.getElementById('panelTxt').innerHTML)"></button>
                <textarea id="panelTxt" class=textarea>Insert text here</textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see I want when I press the button to get the `INNERHtml` from the `textarea`.

Is there any easy way to get the `parent` of the element from where make the call ( in my case the button) and get another child by its id?

So what I need is ..given a `div` with an `id` i want to access its child with a given `id`. What is the easiest way of doing this?

```
<div id="panel">
   <button id="c1"></button>
   <textarea id="c2"></textarea>
</div>
```

Is there a way to query the children like this or similar ?

```
document.getElemenyById("panel")["c1"]
```

Comment: **1.** What you are doing is perfect. **2.** Why do you need the parent?

Comment: There should be no HTML within a `textarea`. You should be using `.value`. `innerHTML` would only ever return "Insert text here" even after the value has changed.

Comment: I need the parent for grouping ,since this is just a small part of a hierachy.I need to acess them by parent and then within the parent by id.

Comment: document.getElementById('Panel')

Comment: I wanted a default value in the `textarea` that is why i added the `HTML`.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian But `.innerHTML` will only ever return your default value - even of a user has typed into the textarea. This is why you need to use `.value` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) on the [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) or [`parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) of the button to access the `textarea` `value`

```js
function method(str) {
  console.log(str);
}
```

```html
<div id="Panel">
  <button id="panelBtn" class="button"   
    onclick="method(this.parentNode.querySelector('#anyTextAreaId').value)">Click</button>
  <textarea id="anyTextAreaId" class=textarea>Insert text here</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this work for `id` as well ? I will have more `textarea`-s and i need to somehow given a `div` acess the children by the `id`.By parent i mean the `div` named `Panel`.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian yes, just use the id in the querySelector parameter  preceeded by a `#`

Comment: However if you have IDs they need to be unique, then you do not need to access via parent. Just `onclick="method(document.getElementById('#anyUniqueTextAreaId').innerHTML)"`

Comment: @mplungjan dont need to go up to the document root if all the textareas are inside the `div#Panel`

Comment: @BelowtheRadar True.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="button" onclick="method( document.getElementById("panelTxt").value )"></button>
```

Don't include the # in your ID of getElementById as suggested in comments.

Answer (score 1):

First I suggest avoiding the use of inline-event `onclick` and attach the event in your JS code using `addEventListener()`, then it will be better to use `nextElementSibling` property and get the content of the next field using `value`:

```js
document.getElementById('panelBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(this.nextElementSibling.value);
})
```

```html
<div id="Panel">
  <button id="panelBtn" class="button">Click Me</button>
  <textarea id="panelTxt" class="textarea">Insert text here</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an unobtrusive way to get the value of the textarea after ANY button in the panel

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".panel>button").forEach(function(but) {
  but.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.nextElementSibling.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="panel1" class="panel">
   <button id="c1">Click</button>
   <textarea id="c2">value 1</textarea>
</div>
<div id="panel2" class="panel">
   <button id="c3">Click</button>
   <textarea id="c4">value 2</textarea>
</div>
```

Here is a way to get any textarea in the parent container

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".panel>button").forEach(function(but) {
  but.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.closest("div").querySelector("textarea").value);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="panel1" class="panel">
   <button id="c1">Click</button>
   <textarea id="c2">value 1</textarea>
</div>
<div id="panel2" class="panel">
   <button id="c3">Click</button>
   <textarea id="c4">value 2</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using: `this.parentElement.querySelector("#panelTxt")`

but take note that id should be unique, so if you plan to have multiple panels, I would suggest that you use class/name selectors instead.

something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <script src="main.js"></script>
        <p>Welcome to Adrian's script</p>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Panel">
                <button id="panelBtn" class="button" onclick="method(this.parentElement.querySelector('.textarea').innerHTML)"></button>
                <textarea id="panelTxt" class="textarea">Insert text here</textarea>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```